# Gradients give the wrong color on iOS mobile safari

Tags: ios, css, cordova, gradient

I'm developing a mobile app with Cordova Phonegap that uses gradients that stack on top of eachother. On Android everything works as it is supposed to but on iOS the gradients shows up different. The edges are green whereas when I preview it in my browser it is blue as it's supposed to be. There's also this weird transition at the bottom of the page.

[image]

This is my css:

```
#gradient2Layer1 {
position: fixed;
height: 100px;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
height: 20%;
width: 100%;
color = "blue";
background:  -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(15,431,28,0) 35%, #b3c6ff 50%,rgb(128,128,128) 100%);
z-index: 100;  }

#gradient2Layer2 {
position: fixed;
height: 100px;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
height: 20%;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0.5;
color = "blue";
background:  -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(15,431,28,0) 35%, blue 50%, blue 100%);
animation: fadeIn 5s infinite alternate;
z-index: 100;  }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `rgba(15,431,28,0)` ? How can `431` fit into the `0..255` range? No wonder that's a bright green color.

Comment: Hmm that's certainly an oversight, but the android version has the same mistake in the code and that's working as it's supposed to

Comment: If I were Safari, I'd clip this value to 255, so `rgba(15,255,28,0)` would be a bright green. Still transparent, but a very very bright green.

Comment: Hmm that's probably the source of the problem. I guess I copied the code from somewhere else. The opacity is set to 0 anyway so no idea why I included it. Perhaps Android doesn't show it because it recognized the 0 opacity and iOS doesn't

Comment: A gradient from a fully-transparent green to a fully-opaque white would still show green pixels. Try it in any image editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really believe this is a typo and you wanted to use `rgba(15,43,128,0)` (which is the shade of blue you're looking for) instead of `rgba(15,431,28,0)`, which is not even a valid RGB value (limited to 0..255).

Comment: Ahh that was what happened. Thank you!